# How to pass an object to HTML In Django view.py

Tags: python, django, django-views, view

I am learning django & web development and find it hard to figure out how the HTML takes request and display information.

In the below code, I want to get the first book object(with two attribute 'title''author') and pass it to the display.html to display the attribute info of the book object. When I am trying the code below

```
def test_display(request):
    request = book.objects.all()[0]
    return render_to_response('display.html', RequestContext(request));
```

Error message is displayed like this.

> 'book' object has no attribute 'META'

But in my book class in the models.py META is defined. What is the problem here? Am i not supposed to pass the object as request?? Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot pass a model instance to `RequestContext`, because `RequestContext` was designed to work with `HttpRequest` instance. See [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext).

If you want to display your model instance in the template, just pass it in the normal context, like this:

```
def test_display(request):
    book = book.objects.all()[0]
    return render_to_response('display.html', {'book': book})
```

Then your template can look like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>{{ book.title }}</li>
  <li>{{ book.author }}</li>
</ul>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi alecxe, thanks so much, the reference is very good and now much clearer on the concepts, Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Uh, you're using `RequestContext` wrong. It's not expecting a model instance...

Remove the line that says `request = book.objects.all()[0]`

```
 def test_display(request):
         request = book.objects.all()[0]
         # ^^^^^^ you're redefining request
         return render_to_response('display.html', RequestContext(request));
                                                                         # ^ why;
```

Also assuming you were trying to use RequestContext as a way to pass your book to the template, you need to pass it a second argument which is a dictionary of context var names to values.

```
RequestContext(request, {'book': book.objects.all()[0]})
```